# Smoke from ship's chimney Smoke should move with the ship

Tags: constraints, smoke-simulation, ocean-simulation

I want the smoke from the chimney to move along with the ship. With "Copy Location" and "Offset" checked, I can position it accordingly and the smoke goes with it. Now I would like to include the rotation of the ship, but with "Copy Rotation" I can no longer align the smoke correctly. With other objects you can simply go to "Edit Mode", change the position and rotation there and then everything fits. But with OpenVDB files like smoke you can't get into edit mode. Is there a way to go into edit mode with an OpenVDB or do you know in any other way how I can correctly position the smoke so that it goes with all movements of the ship?

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try "Child of" constraint?

Comment: Hello Josh, thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

With "Child of" constraint it works :)